# Rails Stripe integration no active card error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Trying to charge a customer for a product registration. I've been following this tutorial [upskillcourses.com](http://upskillcourses.com/courses/essential-web-developer-course/lectures/1746936). Which sets up a subscription. I' just trying to create a charge for a product.

I keep getting this `error`:
`Stripe::CardError in Roadregistrations::RegistrationsController#create
Cannot charge a customer that has no active card`

I've setup the `stripe.js` file:

## app/assets/javascripts/

```
/* global $, Stripe */
//Document ready.
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
var theForm = $('#payment-form');
var submitBtn = $('#form-submit-btn');

//Set Stripe public key.
Stripe.setPublishableKey( $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content') );
//When user clicks form submit btn,
submitBtn.click(function(event){
//prevent default submission behavior.
event.preventDefault();
submitBtn.val("Processing").prop('disabled', true);
//Collect the credit card fields.
var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
    cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
    expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
    expYear = $('#card_year').val();
//Use Stripe JS library to check for card errors.
var error = false;
//Validate card number.
if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
  error = true;
  alert('The credit card number appears to be invalid');
}
//Validate CVC number.
if(!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
  error = true;
  alert('The CVC number appears to be invalid');
}
//Validate expiration date.
if(!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
  error = true;
  alert('The expiration date appears to be invalid');
}
if (error) {
  //If there are card errors, don't send to Stripe.
  submitBtn.prop('disabled', false).val("Register and Pay");
} else {
  //Send the card info to Stripe.
  Stripe.createToken({
    number: ccNum,
    cvc: cvcNum,
    exp_month: expMonth,
    exp_year: expYear
  }, stripeResponseHandler);
}
return false;
});

//Stripe will return a card token.
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
//Get the token from the response.
var token = response.id;
//Inject the card token in a hidden field.
theForm.append($('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]">').val(token));
//Submit form to our Rails app.

theForm.get(0).submit();
}
});
```

Which it seems like the `token` is not being submitted with the form.

Not sure if I need both of these in my `users_controller.rb`:

```
# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def roadregistration_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :phone, :roadshowcity, :stripe_card_token, :comments)
end

protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:stripe_card_token, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :company, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :roadshowcity, :comments) }
  end
```

Then I have this in my `user model`:

```
attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
# If user passes validations (email, pass, etc.),
# Call stripe and tell stripe to set up a subscription
def save_with_registration
  if valid?
    @product_price = Objective.find(objective_id)
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, card: stripe_card_token, description: stripe_card_token.to_s)

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => 9500,
        :currency => "usd",
        :description => "Roadshow Registration"
      )
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
```

`customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: 'example@gma.com')
 => #<Stripe::Customer:0x3ffd3a10e024 id=cus_A5CWbyto5ugmju> JSON: {
  "id": "cus_A5CWbyto5ugmju",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1486585998,
  "currency": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "example@gma.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_A5CWbyto5ugmju/sources"},
  "subscriptions": {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_A5CWbyto5ugmju/subscriptions"}
}`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to link card to the customer after creating the customer on stripe and before charging him:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email)
customer.sources.create(card: stripe_card_token) # <-- this
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(..
```

And I would advice to not send stripe_card_token in the customer object.

If you are on a version older than 2015-02-18 API version replace `sources` with `cards`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that just gives me an error of: `undefined method `cards' for #<Stripe::Customer:`. And looking on the stripe api doc's, there isn't a `customer.cards` object.

Comment: Can you post the result of `customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: 'example@gma.com')` on your rails console.

Comment: I've added the output to my stackoverflow question.

Comment: I realised I wrote the answer for an older version of the API. Have updated the answer.

Comment: So I tried that and am still getting an error. My javascript is definitely not sending the hidden input of the `stripe_card_token`. So I need to figure out why that's not running...

Comment: `el = document.createElement('input'); `
`el.type = "hidden"`
`el.name="user[stripe_card_token]"`
`el.value = 'token'`
`theForm.appendChild(el)`

Comment: You can see the parameters reaching your rails server in your console running the server. Check if the above js change sends the `stripe_card_token`

Comment: The issue was that the turbolinks were not loading. Which in turn kept the javascript from starting. Fixed the turbolinks issue, and now I get the stripe_card_token.

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks was not being loaded in the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file. Fixing that issue allowed the stripe javascript to run and passed the stripe_card_token along.